# Responsive form with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form with the following layout on desktops:

```
Label1  Label2  Label3
input1  input2  input3

Label4  Label5  Label6
input4  input5  input6
```

On mobile devices, I want it to render with the following layout:

```
Label1
input1
Label2
input2
...
```

I am using bootstrap, but with no success.
Here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8t8u9aqy/

Comment: add your html here or set up a fiddle

Comment: You can refer to the Bootstrap "inline forms" documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: See this pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEojWX (resize your window)

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt appear to be using bootstrap?

Answer (score 3):

This will display 3 columns on medium devices and collapse down to one column on mobiles.

```
<form>
...
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-12'>
       ...form element...
    </div>
    ...Repeat for all form elements...
</div>
...
</form>
```

Comment: I tried but in my fiddle I don't obtain what I want

Answer (score 1):

Use this bootstrap form layout with resposive

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text1" placeholder="Enter text1">
    </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text2" placeholder="Enter text2">
    </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text3:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text3" placeholder="Enter text3">
    </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text4:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text4" placeholder="Enter text4">
    </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text5:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text5" placeholder="Enter text5">
    </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text6:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text6" placeholder="Enter text6">
    </div>  
   </div>
   </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```